# sharpdx effect couldn't accelerate

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, sharpdx

we apply a d2dcontext effect gaussianblureffect to a JPG file 4000*3000 32bit , sharpdx takes 270ms , c++ dx version takes 6ms,  seems that the graphic accelerate was not functional. the sharpdx code is below.

```
enter  var desc = new SwapChainDescription()
        {
            BufferCount = 1,
            ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(Width, Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
            IsWindowed = true,
            OutputHandle = this.Handle,
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
            SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
            Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
        };

        // Create Device and SwapChain
        SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport,
            new[] { SharpDX.Direct3D.FeatureLevel.Level_10_0 }, desc, out _device, out _swapChain);

        // Ignore all windows events
        SharpDX.DXGI.Factory factory = _swapChain.GetParent<SharpDX.DXGI.Factory>();
        factory.MakeWindowAssociation(this.Handle, WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);//改这个换渲染的

        Factory2D = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory();

        _backBuffer = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(_swapChain, 0);


        _backBufferView = new RenderTargetView(_device, _backBuffer);
        _d3DDeviceContext = _device.ImmediateContext;
        _d3DDeviceContext.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets(_backBufferView);
        _d3DDeviceContext.ClearRenderTargetView(_backBufferView, ColorToRaw4(SharpDX.Color.Gray));


        using (var surface = BackBuffer.QueryInterface<Surface>())//texture2d
     using (var dxgiDevice = _device.QueryInterface<dxgi.Device>())//d3d11
        {
            //这里设置了RenderTarget2D的工厂，绘图表面为FORM1（前边有配置）
            RenderTarget2D = new RenderTarget(Factory2D, surface, new RenderTargetProperties(new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(Format.Unknown, AlphaMode.Premultiplied)));
            RenderTarget2D2 = new RenderTarget(Factory2D, surface, new RenderTargetProperties(new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(Format.Unknown, AlphaMode.Premultiplied)));


            d2dDevice = new d2.Device(dxgiDevice); // initialize the D2D device
            d2dContext = new d2.DeviceContext(d2dDevice, d2.DeviceContextOptions.EnableMultithreadedOptimizations);// initialize the DeviceContext - it will be the D2D render target and will allow all rendering operations


            //  d2dContext = new d2.DeviceContext(surface);


            var d2PixelFormat = new d2.PixelFormat(dxgi.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm, d2.AlphaMode.Premultiplied);
            var d2dBitmapProps = new d2.BitmapProperties1(d2PixelFormat, 96, 96, d2.BitmapOptions.Target | d2.BitmapOptions.CannotDraw);


            d2dContext.Target = new d2.Bitmap1(d2dContext, surface, d2dBitmapProps);

            sen();
        } here
```

thanks

Comment: var bitmapSourceEffect = new d2.Effects.BitmapSource(d2dContext);
            bitmapSourceEffect.WicBitmapSource = formatConverter;

            //// Effect 2 : GaussianBlur - give the bitmapsource a gaussian blurred effect
            var cutrotEffect = new d2.Effects.AffineTransform2D(d2dContext);

            cutrotEffect.SetInput(0, bitmapSourceEffect.Output, true);

            cutrotEffect.TransformMatrix = _m32final;

Comment: d2dContext.BeginDraw();

            d2dContext.Clear(ColorToRaw4(SharpDX.Color.Gray));//清除轨迹，要放在BEGINDRAW之后
            d2dContext.DrawImage(cutrotEffect);
            //       d2dContext.DrawTextLayout(new Vector2(5f, 5f), textLayout, textBrush);
            d2dContext.EndDraw();
            _swapChain.Present(1, PresentFlags.None);

Comment: You should show both codes not only SharpDX, reformat your question, remove non-english texts, and update your question instead of adding code in comments